# Can $(SolutionDir) variable be used in a Visual Studio publish profile?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, publish, pubxml

Using Visual Studio 2017, in the solution explorer, I right-click on a C# .Net Core project and select "Publish...".  I create a publish profile that publishes the app to a folder or file share.  The result is a profile whose default target location is an absolute path "[project directory]\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\", such as in the following snippet.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Publish Profile Settings dialog]

Visual Studio generates a `.pubxml` file to store that publish profile, where the target location is stored in a `<PublishDir>` tag.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>F:\work\foo\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What I would prefer is to use a variable in the value of the `<PublishDir>` tag, such as the `$(SolutionDir)` variable.  I can manually edit the `.pubxml` file to inject a variable.  For example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <PublishDir>$(SolutionDir)\publish\</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However, when I next load the project in Visual Studio, that variable is either ignored, or has a empty value, such as in the following snippet.

[image]

Is there a way to use variables in the publish profile?

Comment: [No](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/file-pubxml-lost-environment-variable/179197)

Comment: Alas poor Yorick!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem using VS2019. Only things that worked for me where environment variables like `$(windir)` and Properties in the `pubxml` above the line where they are needed e.g.

```
<!-- removed some properties from xml -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishUrl>$(WINDIR)\$(PublishProvider)\$(WebPublishMethod)\$(LastUsedBuildConfiguration)_$(TargetFramework)</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The resulting PublishUrl was

```
C:\Windows\FileSystem\\Release_netcoreapp3.1
```

`WebPublishMethod` is not part of `PublishUrl` because it's below `PublishUrl`.

Don't know about `F:\work\foo\bin\` but you could try Configuration and `TargetFramework` for `Release\netcoreapp2.1`